# Range missing in MapInfo legend

Tags: mapinfo, legend

Is it possible in MapInfo (Version 10) to show in the legend all the ranges created in a thematic map even though the record count for one specific range is 0?

I have to create several thematic maps with the same ranges (and legend) in order to be compared to each other, but some maps don't have objects with the value of some range, therefore the legend comes out with "a gap".

In the following example, I miss the range "2000 - 3000":

[image]

... even though I created 6 ranges in the customize ranges window and formated the 6 ranges in the customize range styles window:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can especifically tick "show this Range" even if there are 0 objects.

It seems that, by default, if there are no values within one specific range, the legend won't show such range. The check box "Show this Range" also seems to tick or untick by itself depending on the option "Show Record Count". So this is good to keep in mind, especially when one is generating many different thematic maps.

[image]